# How to decrypt passphrase-protected SSH key using Fabric and fabfile?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, fabric

I'm in the process of [GettingStarted](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/getting-started.html) with Fabric 2.4.0 and I cannot figure out an elegant and secure way to decrypt my SSH key to pass it to Fabric. My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""fabfile"""
from fabric import Connection

c = Connection('user@ip.address')
result = c.run('uname -s')
```

On this simple example, running `python fabfile.py` I get the error:

```
File "/Users/user.name/GitHub/app_name/fabfile.py", line 6, in <module>
result = c.run('uname -s')
File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in run
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 29, in opens
self.open()
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 615, in open
self.client.connect(**kwargs)
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 437, in connect
passphrase,
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 749, in _auth
raise saved_exception
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 720, in _auth
filename, pkey_class, passphrase
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 571, in _key_from_filepath
key = klass.from_private_key_file(key_path, password)
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 206, in from_private_key_file
key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 55, in __init__
self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 175, in _from_private_key_file
data = self._read_private_key_file("RSA", filename, password)
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 279, in _read_private_key_file
data = self._read_private_key(tag, f, password)
File "/Users/user.name/anaconda/envs/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 329, in _read_private_key
raise PasswordRequiredException("Private key file is encrypted")
paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted
```

1. How can I get Fabric and paramiko to ask me for my Encryption passphrase running the fabfile above?
2. Is `python fabfile.py` an acceptable syntax to run the commands above?
3. What is the best security practice for automatically passing an SSH key from a user's computer to a script in 2018? Is using `os.environ()` acceptable?

I see in the docs on [authentication](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/concepts/authentication.html), Fabric notes `The connect_kwargs.passphrase config option is the most direct way to supply a passphrase to be used automatically.`

But then immediately afterward it says:

> Using actual on-disk config files for this type of material isn’t
>   always wise, but recall that the configuration system is capable of
>   loading data from other sources, such as your shell environment or
>   even arbitrary remote databases.

I'm concerned about setting this up the wrong way from a security standpoint. Is using environment variables to pass the ssh passphrase secure enough? If so, what does a working code snippet look like to get this command to work with an SSH key that is encrypted?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""fabfile"""
from fabric import Connection

c = Connection('user@ip.address')
result = c.run('uname -s')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user of your script can be prompted for a passphrase for the SSH key before executing commands with the CLI option.

This takes care of merging the passphrase in the [`connect_kwargs`](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/2.4.0/fabric/main.py#L133) options forwarded to Paramiko.

```
fab --prompt-for-passphrase <command>
```

The issue with the above approach is having to enter the passphrase every time you run a command.

As advised in the docs, you can export an environment variable in your shell session. *e.g.*

```
export SSH_PASSPHRASE="gongo-aso!"
```

This can then be read from and used in the `connect_kwargs` options passed to the constructor for the `Connection` object.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""fabfile"""
from os import getenv
from fabric import Connection

connect_kwargs = {
    'passphrase': getenv('SSH_PASSPHRASE')
}

c = Connection('user@ip.address', connect_kwargs=connect_kwargs)
result = c.run('uname -s')
```

Comment: Note that (at least) as of `fabric 2.7.1`, this answer results in an `SSHException: Invalid key` error. This can be avoided by changing `'passphrase': ...` to `'password': ...`:)